# MKMapView top offset when presented in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview

I have a problem that is driving me nuts.

In my app, I have a UIViewController with a header UIView and a UITableView below the header. The view controller is presented in a UINavigationController.

The header view has a subview, which in turn has an embedded MKMapView subview. If I refresh the map view on `viewWillAppear(...)` the map looks perfect:

[image: Perfectly placed pin]

However, if I refresh the map anytime after `viewDidAppear(...)` or leave the page by pushing a new view on the stack, the pin gets offset:

[image: Offset pin]

If I present the view without a navigation controller, this problem does not appear.

I have tried setting the `edgesForExtendedLayout` to none, but that caused the navigation bar area to be hidden altogether.

I have tried setting the visible rect for the map view, but that did not make any difference.

Is there any other way to make the map view not care about being presented in a navigation controller?